# RecyclerView overlap data when updating

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem upon fetching my data in `RecyclerView`. If I adding a data, my data was updated but it will overlap one another. Below is the code that I have implemented to achieve the same:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Schedule");

           ArrayList<ScheduleDisplayDetails> get = new ArrayList<>();
                    while (c.moveToNext()) {
                        ScheduleDisplayDetails details = new ScheduleDisplayDetails();
                        details.setID(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ScheduleId")));
                        details.setLocation(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ScheduleLocation")));
                        details.setLatitude(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ScheduleLatitude")));
                        details.setExpectedTimeOfTransaction(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ScheduleExpectedTimeOfTransaction")));
                        details.setEstimatedTimeOfDeparture(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ScheduleEstimatedTimeOfDeparture")));
                        details.setLongitude(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ScheduleLongitude")));
                        details.setStatus(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ScheduleStatus")));
                        get.add(details);
                    }
                    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                    RecyclerView recyclerView = inflatedView.
                            findViewById(R.id.scheduleRecycler);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

                    ScheduleModuleAdapter recyclerViewAdapter =
                            new ScheduleModuleAdapter(get);

                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

This is the adapter that i have written for recyclerview:

```
             private List<NavDrawerFleetGetterSetter> navlist;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView lat, lon, dateTime;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            lat = view.findViewById(R.id.non_map_lat);
            lon = view.findViewById(R.id.non_map_lon);
            dateTime = view.findViewById(R.id.non_map_date_time);

        }
    }


    public NavDrawerFleetAdapter(List<NavDrawerFleetGetterSetter> navDrawerList) {
        this.navlist = navDrawerList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_non_map_card_view, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NavDrawerFleetGetterSetter sched = navlist.get(position);
        holder.lat.setText(sched.getLat());
        holder.lon.setText(sched.getLon());
        holder.dateTime.setText(sched.getDateTime());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return navlist.size();
    }
```

this is my costumizeExemptionHandler(design) used to handle exceptions.

```
         public class CustomizedExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;
    private String localPath;
    public CustomizedExceptionHandler(String localPath) {
        this.localPath = localPath;
        //Getting the the default exception handler
        //that's executed when uncaught exception terminates a thread
        this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {

        //Write a printable representation of this Throwable
        //The StringWriter gives the lock used to synchronize access to this writer.
        final Writer stringBuffSync = new StringWriter();
        final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringBuffSync);
        e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        String stacktrace = stringBuffSync.toString();    
        printWriter.close();

        if (localPath != null) {
            writeToFile(stacktrace);
        }

        defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);
    }

    private void writeToFile(String currentStacktrace) {
        try {

            //Gets the Android external storage directory & Create new folder Crash_Reports
            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "Crash_Reports");
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            String filename = dateFormat.format(date) +".PAkultie";

            // Write the file into the folder
            File reportFile = new File(dir, filename);
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(reportFile);
            fileWriter.append(currentStacktrace);
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ExceptionHandler", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

this is my update (once):
[image]

this is my update request twice:
[image]

this is my update with multiple requests:
[image]

Comment: you need to show how you update your data

Comment: I've try to upload the images but it's not working.. i dont know why but im trying

Comment: I dont see the deference of images, and add your "update data" code

Comment: did you see it?

Comment: no need to add images, explain what do you mean "update request" what code will work?

Comment: if you see the images, the problem is having a white spaces betweeen my data. the more request =space expanding.. ps. getting my data from retrofit is fine, just the spaces created when i am requesting... it is expanding

Comment: in this process, ive like to reset my recyclerview to clean before getting data from api  so that the  white space will not grow even i have multiple request

Comment: now I understand) and see margin. And if you clean your recycler before update you dont have this problem?

Comment: yes, but i dont know the code how to clean it... also i am noticing the decoration.. maybe, it's the one did the margin

Comment: when you make your update your `onViewCreated` works from start?

Comment: from the button update( the yellow one ) also yes, its the same on on created view (recyclerview part)

Comment: check if your code calls `recyclerView.addItemDecoration()` multiple times for the same `RecyclerView`